# Iterar un documento de texto y sacar cuántas veces aparece cada letra, con Python

Tags: python

La idea del programa es que itere por un archivo.txt, saque la cantidad de letras que tiene y cuántas veces se repite cada letra para después sacar la frecuencia de aparición de cada una. El problema está en que no logro que itere por todas las letras del archivo: intenté armar un diccionario donde la clave fuera cada letra y el valor la cantidad de veces que aparece, pero el diccionario almacena solo cuatro letras.
El archivo contiene este texto:

```
But, soft! what light through yonder window breaks?
It is the east, and Juliet is the sun.
Arise, fair sun, and kill the envious moon,
Who is already sick and pale with grief,
```

```
 romeo=open("nuevo romeo.txt")
 diccionario_letras=dict()
 longitud=0
 contador=0
 for linea in romeo:
     linea=linea.lower()
     linea=linea.translate(str.maketrans(" "," ",string.punctuation))
     longitud=longitud+len(linea)
     if len(linea)>0:
         letra=linea[contador]
         diccionario_letras[letra]=diccionario_letras.get(letra,0)+1
         contador=contador+1


 print(longitud)
 print(diccionario_letras)
```

Comment: `diccionario_letras = collections.Counter(romeo.read())`

Answer (score 1):

Una solución:

```
from collections import defaultdict

total = defaultdict(int)
with open("new_romeo.txt", "r") as archivo:
    for linea in archivo.readlines():
        for letra in linea.lower():
            if letra.isalpha():
                total[letra] += 1
```

El diccionario `total` contendrá los totales por letra. Es un *defaultdict*, que tiene la gracia de crear automáticamente las entradas cuando se le pide una llave inexistente. En este caso, con la declaración

```
total = defaultdict(int)
```

el valor para inicializar es un `int` con valor cero.

Luego de abrir el archivo, lo recorremos línea a línea con

```
for linea in archivo.readlines():
```

Y cada línea la recorremos carácter a carácter con

```
for letra in linea.lower():
```

Si el carácter examinado es una letra, sumamos 1 a la correspondiente entrada en el diccionario.

#### Demo

```
from collections import defaultdict

total = defaultdict(int)
with open("new_romeo.txt", "r") as archivo:
    for linea in archivo.readlines():
        for letra in linea.lower():
            if letra.isalpha():
                total[letra] += 1

for letra, cuenta in total.items():
    print(letra, cuenta)
```

produce:

```
b 2
u 6
t 12
s 11
o 8
f 3
w 5
h 9
a 11
l 6
i 14
g 3
r 7
y 2
n 9
d 6
e 12
k 3
j 1
v 1
m 1
c 1
p 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que estás estudiando diccionarios y sus métodos, ésta sería una posible solución:

```
with open('texto.txt') as archivo:
    texto = archivo.read()
```

lee el archivo completo

```
diccionario_letras = {}
```

crea el diccionario

```
for letra in texto.lower():
    if letra.isalpha():
        diccionario_letras.setdefault(letra, 0)
        diccionario_letras[letra] += 1
```

el método lower solo es necesario si no hay que distinguir entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

el condicional isalpha es para que no estén los caracteres que no sean letras propiamente dichas

setdefault es un método que crea las claves sino existen y con el valor declarado como valor

por último si la clave existe se incrementa en 1

```
print(sum(diccionario_letras.values()))
```

sumar los valores de las claves

```
print(diccionario_letras)
```

mostrar el diccionario

código completo:

```
with open('texto.txt') as archivo:
    texto = archivo.read()
    
diccionario_letras = {}

for letra in texto.lower():
    if letra.isalpha():
        diccionario_letras.setdefault(letra, 0)
        diccionario_letras[letra] += 1

print(sum(diccionario_letras.values()))

print(diccionario_letras)
```

Answer (score 0):

Como ha sugerido [abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7123/abulafia) en un comentario, en vez de reinventar la rueda, deberías usar el objeto [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).
Su constructor recibe un iterable cuyos elementos tiene que contar.
El texto que contiene tu archivo será ese iterable.
Para obtener el texto completo de tu archivo usamos el método `read`.
Como además no quieres diferenciar mayúsculas de minúsculas haremos la conversión del texto a minúsculas con `lower`.

```
with open("nuevo romeo.txt", mode='r') as romeo:
    texto_completo = romeo.read().lower()
diccionario_letras = Counter(texto_completo)
```

Esta versión asume que tu archivo de texto es suficientemente pequeño como para tener todo su contenido en memoria.
Si tu archivo fuera demasiado grande puedes hacer:

```
Counter(letra for linea in romeo.readlines()
              for letra in linea.lower())
```

Aquí el diccionario contendrá signos de puntuación y espacios.
Si quieres quitar los símbolos de puntuación de tu diccionario se puede hacer:

```
for simbolo in string.punctuation:
    diccionario_letras.pop(simbolo, None)
```

Si además quisieras saber la cantidad total de caracteres de tu documento puedes usar el método [`Counter.total`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.total).